# Java - How to move a shape

Tags: java, shapes, java-2d, ellipse

So far I am just making a new Shape to "move" it. But is there a better way to change the position of a Shape in Java?

```
// Collision Shape
protected RectangularShape col;

public GameObject() {
    col = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, ObjectSpriteManager.SIZE, ObjectSpriteManager.SIZE);
}

public void tick() {
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
    col = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, ObjectSpriteManager.SIZE, ObjectSpriteManager.SIZE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `setFrame()` methods of `RectangulerShape`.  For example:

```
col.setFrame(x, y, width, height);
```